# If private entities in F# compile to internal, why doesn't InternalsVisibleTo work?

Tags: f#, private, cil, internalsvisibleto

From [the F# 4.0 spec [PDF]](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf):

> The CLI compiled form of all non-public entities is `internal`.

In my main project I have a function defined as

```
namespace MyNamespace.Foo
module Bar =
  module Baz =
    let private myFun ...
```

In the main project's ``AssemblyInfo.fs` I have

```
[<assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyNamespace.Tests")>]
```

(I've double-checked the name.)

However, in the test assembly (also F#), I get an error when referencing `myFun` saying `The value 'myFun' is not accessible from this code location.` Everything works fine if I remove `private` from the definition of `myFun`.

Strangely enough I am also able to call the private `myFun` from a C# project even without `InternalsVisibleTo`.

Why is the private `myFun` not accessible from the test assembly when `private` entities compile to `internal` and I've specified `InternalsVisibleTo` on the main assembly?

Comment: This might be a bit like the fact that for a DU, there are additional methods available that are invisible to F# code.  The compiler may be operating on a different level and using some F# specific metadata.  An interesting test would be whether some C# code can see the private member.

Comment: Yes, it's reachable from C#.

Comment: What you pass to InternalsVisibleTo needs to be an assembly name, not a namespace name.

Comment: I know. The assembly name is `MyNamespace.Tests`.

Comment: Look at the IL produced with `private` and with `internal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a difference between the language level and the compiled code level.

- At language level, `private` behaves as private, so you are only allowed to call the function within the module. If you mark the binding as `internal`, it will behave as internal and you'll be able to call it from the same assembly.
- At compiled code level, `private` s compiled as `internal`, presumably so that you can use things like closures and sequence expressions, but the F# compiler knows that this is just a compilation artifact.

I have not tried this, but I'd guess that if you referenced the assembly from C# then it would behave as `internal` because the C# compiler does not understand the special metadata that the F# compiler puts in to mark the let binding.

Comment: From C# it seems to behave as `public`. I am able to call `private myFun ...` from C# even without `InternalsVisibleTo` on the main assembly.